# Summarize Within 100014 error no luck with Esri help article

Tags: arcpy

Currently using arcpy to run a script to include the [Summarize Within tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm). Unfortunately, I am receiving a `10014 error`. I have already shortened the file path per the help article to the shortest possible and no luck. Seems like there is more to this than the 10014 error.

I am using Python 3.7.11 with arcpy 2.9.

This is the error received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/PlanningTools/KABCO.py", line 97, in <module>
    summarize = arcpy.analysis.SummarizeWithin(buffer, sc_input, ee, keepAll, sumFields)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 2686, in SummarizeWithin
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 2683, in SummarizeWithin
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.SummarizeWithin_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_polygons, in_sum_features, out_feature_class, keep_all_polygons, sum_fields, sum_shape, shape_unit, group_field, add_min_maj, add_group_percent, out_group_table), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 100014: Summarize Within failed.
Failed to execute (SummarizeWithin).
```

And the error code support article - https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000027089

And here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# create folder and gdb
PD_num = "Test_v1"
Folder_v1 = arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Python"
Folder_A = arcpy.management.CreateFolder(
    out_folder_path=Folder_v1, out_name="{}".format(PD_num)
)
print("Folder named {} created".format(PD_num))
Summary_gdb = arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(
    out_folder_path=Folder_A, out_name="Summary", out_version="CURRENT"
)[0]

# some inputs
crash = r"D:\Python\PlanningTools\KABCO\Data\stafford_crash"
crash_input = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
    crash,
    Summary_gdb,
    "crash"
)
segments = r"D:\Python\PlanningTools\KABCO\Data\SegmentTest\Segment_Test.shp"
segment_input = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
    segments, Summary_gdb, "segments"
)


# Create buffer
buffer = arcpy.analysis.Buffer(
    segment_input,
    os.path.join(Summary_gdb, "segments_buffer"),
    "35 Feet",
    "FULL",
    "ROUND",
    "NONE",
    None,
    "PLANAR",
)

# add fields
a = arcpy.management.AddField(
    crash_input,
    "A_crashes",
    "LONG",
    None,
    None,
    None,
    "",
    "NULLABLE",
    "NON_REQUIRED",
    "",
)
b = arcpy.management.AddField(
    crash_input,
    "B_crashes",
    "LONG",
    None,
    None,
    None,
    "",
    "NULLABLE",
    "NON_REQUIRED",
    "",
)
c = arcpy.management.AddField(
    crash_input,
    "C_crashes",
    "LONG",
    None,
    None,
    None,
    "",
    "NULLABLE",
    "NON_REQUIRED",
    "",
)
k = arcpy.management.AddField(
    crash_input,
    "K_crashes",
    "LONG",
    None,
    None,
    None,
    "",
    "NULLABLE",
    "NON_REQUIRED",
    "",
)
o = arcpy.management.AddField(
    crash_input,
    "O_crashes",
    "LONG",
    None,
    None,
    None,
    "",
    "NULLABLE",
    "NON_REQUIRED",
    "",
)


# Calculate fields
aa = arcpy.management.CalculateField(
    crash_input,
    "A_crashes",
    "reclass(!CRASH_SEVE!)",
    "PYTHON3",
    """def reclass(CRASH_SEVE):

    if (CRASH_SEVE == "A"):

        return "1"

    else:

        return "0"

""",
    "TEXT",
    "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS",
)
bb = arcpy.management.CalculateField(
    aa,
    "B_crashes",
    "reclass(!CRASH_SEVE!)",
    "PYTHON3",
    """def reclass(CRASH_SEVE):

    if (CRASH_SEVE == "B"):

        return "1"

    else:

        return "0"

""",
    "TEXT",
    "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS",
)
cc = arcpy.management.CalculateField(
    bb,
    "C_crashes",
    "reclass(!CRASH_SEVE!)",
    "PYTHON3",
    """def reclass(CRASH_SEVE):

    if (CRASH_SEVE == "C"):

        return "1"

    else:

        return "0"

""",
    "TEXT",
    "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS",
)
dd = arcpy.management.CalculateField(
    cc,
    "K_crashes",
    "reclass(!CRASH_SEVE!)",
    "PYTHON3",
    """def reclass(CRASH_SEVE):

    if (CRASH_SEVE == "K"):

        return "1"

    else:

        return "0"

""",
    "TEXT",
    "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS",
)
ee = arcpy.management.CalculateField(
    dd,
    "O_crashes",
    "reclass(!CRASH_SEVE!)",
    "PYTHON3",
    """def reclass(CRASH_SEVE):

    if (CRASH_SEVE == "O"):

        return "1"

    else:

        return "0"

""",
    "TEXT",
    "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS",
)

# inputs for summarize within
sc_summary = os.path.join(Summary_gdb, "sc")
keepAll = "KEEP_ALL"
sumFields = [
    ["A_crashes", "Sum"],
    ["B_crashes", "Sum"],
    ["C_crashes", "Sum"],
    ["K_crashes", "Sum"],
    ["O_crashes", "Sum"],
]
sc_input = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
    ee,
    Summary_gdb,
    "crash_input"
)

# summarize within
summarize = arcpy.analysis.SummarizeWithin(
    buffer,
    sc_input,
    ee,
    keepAll,
    sumFields
)

print(Summary_gdb)

print ("Script complete")
```

Comment: You'd better define and store your codeblock in a string prior to the call to your `CalculateField()` function for readability.

Comment: That section works fine, but is understandable on readability - just copied in to understand what the code does. Everything works perfectly up until #inputs for summarize within

Comment: Please, consider adding the full stack trace and details about your environment (versions of softwares / libraries) to help people helping you. Without this information, it will be pretty hard to give advices.

Comment: If you think this "10014" error is relevant please include a link to it within your question.  I think your coding pattern with things like `a = arcpy.management.AddField()` instead of simply `arcpy.management.AddField()` is astray.

Comment: added error code and more details about the environment.

Comment: Have ran without a = arcpy.management.AddField() and rather arcpy.management.AddField() with no luck. Same with arcpy.management.CalculateField

Comment: @MattMDL, just do a quick check, run the script through ArcGIS Pro's Python IDLE, if it fails there, go ahead and have a quick check with your user profile, I mean just let a head less profile login to your machine and run the same script. This will give you the exact reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [`arcpy.analysis.SummarizeWithin()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm) function:

```
arcpy.analysis.SummarizeWithin(
    in_polygons,
    in_sum_features,
    out_feature_class,
    {keep_all_polygons},
    {sum_fields},
    {sum_shape},
    {shape_unit},
    {group_field},
    {add_min_maj},
    {add_group_percent},
    {out_group_table}
)
```

which takes arguments of these types:

- in_polygons:: `Feature Layer`
- in_sum_features:: `Feature Layer`
- out_feature_class:: `Feature Class`
- keep_all_polygons:: `Boolean` (optional)
- sum_fields:: `Value Table` (optional)
- sum_shape:: `Boolean` (optional)
- shape_unit:: `String` (optional)
- group_field:: `Field` (optional)
- add_min_maj:: `Boolean` (optional)
- add_group_percent:: `Boolean` (optional)
- out_group_table:: `Table` (optional)

Your call is the following:

```py
summarize = arcpy.analysis.SummarizeWithin(
    buffer,
    sc_input,
    ee,
    keepAll,
    sumFields
)
```

with:

- buffer:: `Feature Class`
- sc_input:: `Feature Class`
- ee:: `Table View` OR `Raster Layer` OR `Mosaic Layer`
- keepAll:: `string`
- sumFields:: `list`

Here is the corresponding documentation:

- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm
- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm
- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm
- https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm

So based on that:

I would first `print(f"Type of variable the_name_of_your_variable: {your_variable}")` for **each** of the input arguments you pass to the `SummarizeWithin()` function to check that their *type* is actually correct, as asked by the function.
Because for example, your `buffer` is a `Feature Class` where the function is awaiting for a `Feature Layer`. Same reasoning goes for all your input variables, e.g. `keepAll` should be a boolean as `True` or `False`. Your string is kind of "ok" but keep in mind even if you wrote `keepAll='do_not_keep_all' it will be evaluated to` True`.

So, add those `print()` calls to your code first, then update your question in order to include these *and* their results.
And finally, try to fix your argument types so that they *do actually fit* with what `SummarizeWithin()` is expecting. And again, after that, come with a precise update.

Comment: So, after some testing I updated the buffer and sc_input to be feature layers, update sumFields to be a Value_Table and changed keepAll to be True - no luck. Additionally, I removed all optional parameters and kept only in_polygons, in_sum_features, out_feature_class and that also did not work. As the first two are correct feature layers, I go back to the original error code and out_feature_class again. Quite confused here.

Comment: Furthermore, ran the same script in an ArcGIS Notebook in ArcPro with the same arcpy environment configured and it ran perfectly. The issue lies within PyCharm/something with the interpreter or envrironment... :/ Not sure how to fix that one

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, but the solution was to define the projections on my input Feature Classes not shorten the path length like ESRI suggests.